# Optional returns empty object with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have following code in my test case but when the method `discountCurveReqMapper.getMapping` is called in test case, it returns empty Optional object instead of `DiscountCurveReqMap`  object

Can someone guide on whats the issue here.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class IRSwapValuatorTest {


    @Autowired
    private IRSwapValuator valuator;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private YieldCurveProvider yieldCurveProvider;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @MockBean
    private DiscountCurveReqMapper discountCurveReqMapper;

    @MockBean
    private SDPFixingInstrumentServiceImpl fis;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        .....
        .....

        DiscountCurveReqMap discountCurveReqMap = new DiscountCurveReqMap();
        when(discountCurveReqMapper.getMapping(any(String.class), any(String.class), any(Optional.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(discountCurveReqMap));
        when(fis.load(any(String.class),any(String.class))).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        this.valuator = new IRSwapValuator(restTemplate, applicationProperties, new SimpleMeterRegistry(), yieldCurveProvider, discountCurveReqMapper,fis);
    }
```

Edit:

Signature for getMapping method is :

```
public Optional<DiscountCurveReqMap> getMapping(@NotNull String currency,@NotNull  String type, Optional<String> settlement) {
        String key = currency + "_" + type + "_" + settlement.orElse("");
        return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key));
    }
```

Comment: Mockito has `anyString` btw, it would make this easier to read

Comment: Are you certain that it's being called with `(String, String, Optional)`? Post the signature of `getMapping`.

Comment: @Michael : Added the signature, see the edit.

Comment: Overwriting Autowired `valuator` looks fishy to me. Check if the object you set expectations on is the same that is actually used when executing the code.